# Why is voltage equal across the resistors connected in parallel?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

Say I have a circuit and three resistors connected on parallel. Then if I want to calculate equivalent resistance i use the ohms law(V=IR). Call the three resistors R1,R2,R3 and current passing through them as I1,I2,I3 respectively. Now in my textbook it was given from here as follows:-

Let I=I1+I2+I3, which is the total current passing through the resistor. By ohm's law,

V/R = (V/R1)+(V/R2)+(V/R3)

So the equivalent resistance equals the sum of reciprocals of each  resistor.
The thing which confused me is why is potential difference equal for all of three resistors connected in parallel?
I am confused with the fact that ,if resistance is changing then voltage must also change (by ohm's law) then why isn't it true here?

Comment: Circuit elements in parallel have by definition same potential difference. It's the very definition of parallel connection. The Ohm law states that $V=RI$, so if you have different resistances you may still end up with the same voltage by having different currents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is voltage same for the two resistors connected parallel in circuit?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/638940/)

Answer (score 1):

In a DC circuit, when two resistors are connected in parallel:

[image]

The resistors by definition are connected directly across the terminals of the battery. Therefore, the potential differences across the resistors are the same: $$\Delta V = \Delta V_1 = \Delta V_2$$
By Ohm's law we have $\Delta V = IR$, so even though the resistors have different resistances, the current flowing through the resistors varies inversely with the resistance (more current flows in the branch with lower resistance and vice versa), so as to give the same potential difference (voltage)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a physics question, it's a question of definitions.

Voltage in a circuit is measured between two nodes. "In parallel," *by definition,* means that the resistors all are connected between the same two nodes. When you measure the Voltage across any one of the resistors, you are *by definition,* measuring the Voltage between the same two nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly when any two points are connected by a resistance less wire their potentials become equal. This can be proves as follows. Suppose A and B are connected by a resistance less wire.Then potential difference between A and B is given by Ohm's Law as:
$$V_{AB} = IR$$
But since R is zero , $V_{AB}$ (which is the potential difference between A and B) is also zero i.e both points have the same potential.

Now let the potential of the cathode in the cell be v and that of the anode be $0$.Since points D,E,F are connected to the cathode with a resistance less wire their potentials are also v.

Also since points A,B,C are connected to anode by resistance less wire the potentials of these points is zero.

So across each resistor we have a potential difference of $v-0=v$.

Therefore the equivalent resistance has a potential difference of v across it.

Now to answer your question as to why potential difference does not change when the value of resistance changes let me remind you of Ohm's Law:

$$V = IR$$

When the equivalent resistance becomes half the value of any component  resistance then current through the equivalent resistance becomes double of the current through the component resistance  so the net value of potential difference across the equivalent resistance remains same as that of the component  resistor.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you have not paid attention to the basic equation as
$$ V = IR $$
So in some parallel branching when R is altered, the flowing current through that branch will so inversely change as to keep the product $IR$ constant. As you can practically see, voltage depends on the source of power(or energy) such as battery, not on what resistance the conducting wire has.

As an example, two water tanks placed at different heights and are connected by two pipes (the two pipes are at the same height), the flow of water from higher to lower one will be caused by gravitional potential. Which would not depend on how big or small (comparing size to resistance in wires) the pipes are. (Although it will affect the *rate of flow* which is analogous to current in electrical circuits)